# How to change the input in table cell in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have table and javascript code which should change the value of each input in table. How can I get access to inner cell element?

This is my html code:

```
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
     <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
     <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
     <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
     <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
     <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
     <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
function showSuccess(msg) {
    Messenger({
        extraClasses: 'messenger-fixed messenger-on-right messenger-on-top',
        theme: 'flat'
    }).post(msg);
}

function pushArray(){

    var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
        //gets cells of current row
        var oCells = oTable.rows[i].cells;

        //gets amount of cells of current row
        var cellLength = oCells.length;

       //loops through each cell in current row
       for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

            // here i should change the value of input
            oCells[j].innerHTML="NEW CONTENT";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use td instead of th? Also have you tried stepping through this with the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

you should try to find the textbox you have added inside your header tag

```
oCells[j].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "your value";
```

Working fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/bsmdr2hq/2/

Answer (score 0):

This code works, make sure to include the javascript file and set the onload property of the body.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="pushArray()">
        <table border="1" id="myTable">
          <tr>
             <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
             <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
             <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
             <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
             <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
             <th><input type="text" size="2"></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you think the code works? It replaces the HTML of the table cell, instead of filling in the value of the input.